# Google MAPS .. Unfortunately the program has stopped

Tags: android, google-maps

. I am Trying to make a simple google map program in android application.. but when I launch my app.. unfortunately stopped error Comes..
Please Help Me

Here is MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.mymaps;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
            Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                      .position(CIU).title("My Office"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView        
android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA0MunNdPVAGdely1AS5HsJYhNkszVclFc"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat :

```
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.example.mymaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-01 12:16:21.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: As your   `android:minSdkVersion < 12` so used `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: I have changed the minSDKvErsion to 13.. But Still The Same Error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

under the **application tag** in your manifest.

Then there could be two things:

1) define all of your Activity classes in AndroidManifest.xml class.

2) compile your Android project using "Google APIs" instead of "Android 2.x", If you compile using Google APIs only then It will add Google Maps classes.

Is Google maps installed in the emulator?

Try changing this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

To this:

```
<permission
    android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

I think YOU.PACKAGE is com.example.mymaps

Comment: There Is a red X Showing in front of the project library when the properties or project are opened

Comment: Try with the code I wrote: note you Have two times "uses-permission"